# Having trouble accessing updated Contact.Histories in unit test

Tags: unit-test, field-history

I have a custom object to manage patient (Contact) status changes, which affect product shipments.  I'm adding a process to roll back changes based on receiving a cancelled form, based on a common form.Id from an external system.  Patient_Status__c is tracked in field history, and I created this method to retrieve the most recent past values for a group:

```
    public Map<Id, Contact> mapPatientsById(Set<Id> setPatientIds) {
    mapPatientsById = new Map<Id, Contact>(
        [Select Id, AccountId, Name, 
                Patient_Status__c,
                (SELECT NewValue, OldValue FROM Histories
                 WHERE Field ='Patient_Status__c'
                 ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1)
         from   Contact
         where  Id in :setPatientIds]);

    return mapPatientsById;
}
```

and this one to return either the previous value, or the current value if there's no history on the field

```
    public static String getPriorPatientStatus(Contact c){
    if (c.Histories == null || c.Histories.isEmpty()) return c.Patient_Status__c;
    return (String)c.Histories[0].OldValue;
}
```

In the UI, cancelling a status change seems to be working as intended.

In my test(s), I insert both a Contact and associated status change record before test.startTest(), which should create field history data, and then insert my cancel form after.  If I check Contact.Histories[] when I insert the cancellation, I'm not finding them, so there is no 'prior status' to restore, and the test fails.

Here's my test scenario:

```
    patient = UT_Utils.reGetContact(patient.Id);
    patient.Patient_Status__c = 'Active';
    Utils.DatabaseUpdate(patient);

    statusForm = new Status_Form__c();
    statusForm.Form_Id__c = formId;        
    statusForm.Contact__c = patient.Id;

    insert statusForm;
    patient = UT_Utils.reGetContact(patient.Id);
    System.assertEquals('On Hold (Trans/Hosp)', patient.Patient_Status__c, 'Incorrect interim status for Patient Status ');

    Set<Id> setPatientIds = new Set<Id>{patient.Id};
    Map<Id, Contact> tmpMap = sc.mapPatientsById(setPatientIds);
    Contact tmpC = tmpMap.get(patient.Id);
    Utils.debug(tmpC.Histories.size() + ' Patient Status changes found for Patient ' + tmpC.Full_Name__c);

    test.startTest();

        // Create & submit the cancellation
        cancelForm = new Status_Form__c();
        cancelForm.Form_Id__c = formId;
        cancelForm.Error__c = true;
        cancelForm.Contact__c = patient.Id;
        cancelForm.Account__c = null;
        insert cancelForm;

    test.stopTest();        

    patient = UT_Utils.reGetContact(patient.Id);
    System.assertEquals('Active', patient.Patient_Status__c, 'Incorrect final Patient Status ');
```

I haven't tried to insert the field history data in the test; that feels like bad juju on the face of it.  Any thoughts on how to structure this differently to get access to field history from that test setup data?

Comment: I've linked a relevant question that I think should give you everything you need to know. If not, though, please let us know and we'll be glad to reopen the question for you.